# Convert python dictionary to one string

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to convert a python dictionary to one string
Example:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

should be

```
key1=value1; key2=value2; key3=value3
```

I tried to search for such a topic but didn't find any clue

This is my try but I am seeking to learn

```
tmp = ''
for cookie in cookies_dic:
    tmp = tmp + ';' + cookie + '=' + cookies_dic[cookie]

print(tmp[1:])
```

Comment: But what did you try kwa code?

Comment: `'; '.join(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in dct.items())`?

Comment: In Python 3.6+ (b/c of f-strings), for a dictionary `d`: `'; '.join([f"{k}={v}" for (k,v) in d.items()])`.  The same general idea could be used for older python versions replacing the f-string interpolation with, e.g. `%` interpolation.  Also note, you actually _do_ want to explicitly create a list here instead of just passing `join` a generator (without `[`,`]`).

Comment: @jedwards no need for an intermediate `list`. You can just hand `str.join()` a generator expression.

Comment: I already did my attempt. But I am seeking to learn new techniques

Comment: @Axe319, I knew someone was going to say that -- I just updated my comment to make it clear that you _do_ want an explicit list and not just the generator.  See [this](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1374826259482439681), the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447081/python-generator-objects-and-join), [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26148197), etc.

Comment: @jedwards good point. I did not know that. I'll have to start following Hettinger.

Comment: What's wrong with `repr(cookies_dic)`?

Comment: @MarkRansom What does this line do?

Comment: Try it and find out.

Comment: I already tried before asking the question. It returns the same dictionary as output

Answer (score 1):

```
d={'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
result=''
for i,j in d.items():
     result+=i+'='+j+';'
print(result)

key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;
```

Comment: Nooo, please don't build strings this way -- they're immutable and you're creating and discarding all the intermediate ones.

Comment: The result isn't what OP wants, either. This has a trailing semicolon.

Comment: I used `print(result[:-2])` at the end

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
t = []
for i in d:
   t.append(f"{i} : {d[i]}")  
s = " ;".join(t)
print(s)
```